# Apache redirect to different port for docker container ( Redmine )

Tags: apache, docker, redirect, redmine

Hello I am working a project to run Drupal web page and Redmine on the same server. Drupal is main web and using 80 and 443. Redmine is on docker and using 3000 port.

Using httpd proxy setting, I was able to get the Redmine page.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /redmine http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPass /stylesheets http://127.0.0.1:3000/stylesheets/
ProxyPassReverse /stylesheets http://127.0.0.1:3000/stylesheets/
ProxyPass /javascripts http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/
ProxyPassReverse /javascripts http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/
ProxyPass /images http://127.0.0.1:3000/images
ProxyPassReverse /images http://127.0.0.1:3000/images
```

However, when I click buttons on the redmine page such as project, login, register. It's redirected to main domain.

I would like to get `www.example.com/redmine/login`

but it's redirected to `www.example.com/login`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To configure Redmine's URI, you can do it from Redmine itself, navigate to

**admin | settings**

and enter desired configuration to 
**Host name and path** field

And click **save**.

[image]

Additionally, depending upon how Redmine is deployed, deployment specific configuration can be applied, as described on Redmine wiki: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI

Comment: but your proxy pass should then be ProxyPass /javascripts http://127.0.0.1:3000/redmine/javascripts/ instead of ProxyPass /javascripts http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/

Comment: I had to modify the docker container to use sub_rul http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI

Comment: Cool, so you can answer your own question now ;)